# Fatal Error: Undefined function variable_get();

Tags: configuration

I have this, `$metrics = variable_get('rbi_metrics_list_settings',array());`, I have used this in 3-4 pages. And when I put in another file, when I wanted to see what's inside of `$metrics` , it said undefined function. I omitted it and it returned nothing. What seems to be the problem? Please help.

Comment: the tag is actually about variable_get(), but it's not available in the tags list.

Comment: What file are you using this in?

Comment: Also, in which function is that code used?